# Did I solve this right? Simplify $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt[6]{x}}$, I got $\sqrt x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt[6]{x}}$$

I got $\sqrt x$. The question says "Simplify the following expressions (defined in their respective domains)". The domain of the one I got isn't exactly the same as the domain of the one given because of the zero... is this correct? If not where did it go wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
\begin{equation}
\sqrt[3]{x^2} = (x^2)^{1/3} = x^{2/3}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sqrt[6]{x} = (x)^{1/6} = x^{1/6}
\end{equation}
Dividing yields
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{x^{2/3}}{x^{1/6}} = x^{2/3 - 1/6} = x^{4/6 - 1/6} = x^{3/6} = x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x} \quad \textrm{provided $x\neq0$}
\end{equation}
So you are indeed correct! The domain of the latter function does indeed include $x=0$, but as you said, as we had the original fraction, we need to exclude the case $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was going to be one of those simple-at-a-glance-but-actually-complicated ones... do I write anything different in my answer that says the zero is excluded?

Comment: Yes, because it says "...defined in their respective domains."

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire, if you found this answer useful, please mark it as such.